# Native ads is not showing in flutter

Tags: c++, android, flutter, admob, ads

```
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NativeExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const NativeExample({super.key});

  @override
  NativeExampleState createState() => NativeExampleState();
}

class NativeExampleState extends State<NativeExample> {
  NativeAd? _nativeAd;
  bool _nativeAdIsLoaded = false;
  String? _versionString;
  // final double _adAspectRatioSmall = (91 / 355);
  final double _adAspectRatioMedium = (370 / 355);

  final String _adUnitId = 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2247696110';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    MobileAds.instance.updateRequestConfiguration(RequestConfiguration(
        testDeviceIds: ['582750308C87F9B58075658F06F52379']));
    loadAd();
    _loadVersionString();
  }

  void loadAd() {
    _nativeAd = NativeAd(
        adUnitId: _adUnitId,
        listener: NativeAdListener(
          onAdLoaded: (ad) {
            debugPrint('$NativeAd loaded.');
            setState(() {
              _nativeAdIsLoaded = true;
            });
          },
          onAdFailedToLoad: (ad, error) {
            // Dispose the ad here to free resources.
            debugPrint('$NativeAd failed to load: $error');
            ad.dispose();
          },
        ),
        request: const AdRequest(),
        // Styling
        nativeTemplateStyle: NativeTemplateStyle(
            // Required: Choose a template.
            templateType: TemplateType.medium,
            // Optional: Customize the ad's style.
            mainBackgroundColor: Colors.purple,
            cornerRadius: 10.0,
            callToActionTextStyle: NativeTemplateTextStyle(
                textColor: Colors.cyan,
                backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                style: NativeTemplateFontStyle.monospace,
                size: 16.0),
            primaryTextStyle: NativeTemplateTextStyle(
                textColor: Colors.red,
                backgroundColor: Colors.cyan,
                style: NativeTemplateFontStyle.italic,
                size: 16.0),
            secondaryTextStyle: NativeTemplateTextStyle(
                textColor: Colors.green,
                backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                style: NativeTemplateFontStyle.bold,
                size: 16.0),
            tertiaryTextStyle: NativeTemplateTextStyle(
                textColor: Colors.brown,
                backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
                style: NativeTemplateFontStyle.normal,
                size: 16.0)))
      ..load();
  }

  void _loadVersionString() {
    MobileAds.instance.getVersionString().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        _versionString = value;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _nativeAd?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Native Example',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Native Example'),
        ),
        body: SizedBox(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Stack(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *
                        _adAspectRatioMedium,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  ),
                  if (_nativeAdIsLoaded && _nativeAd != null)
                    AdWidget(ad: _nativeAd!),
                ],
              ),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: loadAd,
                child: const Text("Refresh Ad"),
              ),
              if (_versionString != null) Text(_versionString!)
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  /// Loads a native ad.
}
```

Debug Console:

```
Restarted application in 3,656ms.
D/DynamitePackage( 6642): Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraAdLoaderBuilderCreatorImpl
I/Ads     ( 6642): This request is sent from a test device.
W/ConnectionStatusConfig( 6642): Dynamic lookup for intent failed for action: com.google.android.gms.ads.service.CACHE
W/ConnectionStatusConfig( 6642): Dynamic lookup for intent failed for action: com.google.android.gms.ads.service.START
I/Ads     ( 6642): Received log message: <Google:HTML> Incorrect native ad response. Click actions were not properly specified
I/Ads     ( 6642): Ad failed to load : 0
I/flutter ( 6642): NativeAd failed to load: LoadAdError(code: 0, domain: com.google.android.gms.ads, message: Internal error., responseInfo: ResponseInfo(responseId: CNqw1eju0YIDFeMWgwMdqJAE9w, mediationAdapterClassName: , adapterResponses: [AdapterResponseInfo(adapterClassName: com.google.ads.mediation.admob.AdMobAdapter, latencyMillis: 47, description: {
I/flutter ( 6642):   "Adapter": "com.google.ads.mediation.admob.AdMobAdapter",
I/flutter ( 6642):   "Latency": 47,
I/flutter ( 6642):   "Ad Source Name": "Reservation campaign",
I/flutter ( 6642):   "Ad Source ID": "7068401028668408324",
I/flutter ( 6642):   "Ad Source Instance Name": "[DevRel] [DO NOT EDIT] Native Ads Campaign",
I/flutter ( 6642):   "Ad Source Instance ID": "3518433842871043",
I/flutter ( 6642):   "Credentials": {},
I/flutter ( 6642):   "Ad Error": {
I/flutter ( 6642):     "Code": 0,
I/flutter ( 6642):     "Message": "Internal error.",
I/flutter ( 6642):     "Domain": "com.google.android.gms.ads",
I/flutter ( 6642):     "Cause": "null"
I/flutter ( 6642):   }
I/flutter ( 6642): }, adUnitMapping: {}, adError: AdError(code: 0, domain: com.google.android.gms.ads, message: Internal error.), adSourceName: Reservation campaign, adSourceId: 7068401028668408324, adSourceInstanceName: [DevRel] [DO NOT EDIT] Native Ads Campaign, adSourceInstanceId: 3518433842871043)], loadedAdapterResponseInfo: null), responseExtras: {mediation_group_name: Campaign})
D/EGL_emulation( 6642): app_time_stats: avg=112665.77ms min=112665.77ms max=112665.77ms count=1
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvdIo.png)
```

I am trying to load a native ad in fluter but its not working , i have tried mainy ways but i failed !
please help load me my native ads in flutter .
I am trying to load a native ad in fluter but its not working , i have tried mainy ways but i failed !
please help load me my native ads in flutter

Comment: https://developers.google.com/admob/flutter/native/templates  can you please go through the guide